# Addition menu using case of in Pascal

Tags: calculator, pascal

I am trying to add a menu using the `case of` in Pascal. I'm using pascal, what's wrong with this code statement to the case?
This is my program on pascal:

```
program InputNilai;
uses crt;
var
  a,b,h : integer;
  pilihan : char;
begin
  clrscr;
  write('1. Penjumlahan');
  write('2. Perkalian');
  write('Masukkan pilihan: '); readln(pilihan);
  
  // menggunakan kondisi case of
  case (pilihan) of
    A : begin
          write('Masukkan angka pertama: '); readln(a);
          write('Masukkan angka kedua: '); readln(b);
          h := a + b;
          writeln('Result is: ',h);
        end;
    B : begin
          write('Masukkan angka pertama: '); readln(a);
          write('Masukkan angka kedua: '); readln(b);
          h := a * b;
          writeln('Result is ',h);
        end;
    else 
      writeln('Not valid');
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Without () in case -_-

Comment: `case pilihan of 'A' :`  etc. You need to use apostrophes to declare characters.

Comment: Apart from the missing apostrophes, if the user is asked to select either '1. Penjumlahan' or '2. Perkalian', I would expect them to respond with '1' or '2' (not 'A' or 'B').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program InputNilai;

uses crt;

var
  a,b,h : integer;
  pilihan : integer;

begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('1. Penjumlahan');
  writeln('2. Perkalian');
  writeln('Masukkan pilihan: ');
  readln(pilihan);
  
  // menggunakan kondisi case of
  Case pilihan of
    1:begin
        writeln('Masukkan angka pertama: '); readln(a);
        writeln('Masukkan angka kedua: '); readln(b);
        h := a + b;
        writeln('Result is: ',h);
      end;
    2:begin
        writeln('Masukkan angka pertama: '); readln(a);
        writeln('Masukkan angka kedua: '); readln(b);
        h := a * b;
        writeln('Result is ',h);
      end;
  else 
    writeln('Not valid');
  end;

  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you babe, I forget to delete () hahaha, 